# Time Travel vs Conservation of matter and energy

Tags: time-travel

If you were to go back in time, how would you account for the extra matter and energy in the Universe you have created? (the laws of Matter and Energy Conservation). Would not every atom in your body, the oxygen in your lungs and all that you brought with you, already exist as something else?